# Get URL from images in google sheets

Tags: csv, google-sheets, export-to-csv

I've a google sheets with 5000 productss with some information, among which a images.
So, I need to convert this file in csv, for import products, but when I convert the file the column with image is empty, because the image no have a URL, probally because the image has been loaded for local pc.
Which solution exist?
The perfect gol for me would be create a url associate to image, so when I convert the file in csv, the column with image has a url of image.

This is a little copy of file with a 10 items:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16U-0fRnxCVsbM96BBp57w29wDaIy3mtT/edit#gid=1553385073

Thanks!

Comment: I think that in your situation, in order to achieve your goal, it is required to upload those images to Google Drive and other site for retrieving the direct link as the public content. From your question, I couldn't understand whether this method is included in your expected goal. So, can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: How have you implemented your code to associate the images to a URL? optimally, you would need to upload them to Google Drive or any other storage service you can access via URLs so those can be stored in your sheet. Keep in mind that whenever possible, you need to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue using code you have/tried

Comment: Thanks for response.
Add some information: I receved this file excel, the goal was convert it in csv.
So, I can't put the images in cloud because 5000 images is too long, my question is:
starting by this file excel with images, is there a possibile quickly to get a url? Google sheet can automatically save the images in a google drive and create a url?